# Laravel and Bootstrap - Form with no action still sending data

Tags: php, forms, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I'm working on a Laravel site built by someone else and one of the pages has a form on it that doesn't have any action or any obvious location the data gets sent to, yet it still sends data to the back-end.

The form below is found on portal.blade.php - I can't find anything in there resembling Form::

If I delete the classes 'inspiring' & 'submit' from the submit button the form stops working.

Live page: http://amazingyou.bravissimo.com/about

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="inspiring modal fade" 
  id="myModal" 
  tabindex="-1" 
  role="dialog" 
  aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" 
  aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" 
         class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Your Amazing Story</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <p>
            <input class="name" placeholder="Your Name" value="">
          </p>
          <p>
            <input class="title" placeholder="Story Title" value="">
          </p>
          <p>
            <textarea class="story" 
              placeholder="Your Story (max. 150 words)"></textarea>
          </p>
        </form>
        <div class="results" style="display:none">
          Thank you for your Amazing Story
        </div>
        <div class="character-limit" style="display:none">
          Please limit your story to 150 words
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" 
          class="btn btn-default" 
          data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button 
          onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'amazing_story', 'click', 'submit_story');" 
          type="button" 
          class="btn btn-primary inspiring submit">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by the form stops working? Those buttons aren't inside the form, that doesn't make sense. Post your javascript `ga` function

Comment: Hi Fabio, the form wont send when I get rid of the 'inspiring' & 'submit' classes. The ga function is part of google analytics, it only tracks clicks and doesn't change any functionality.

Comment: ohhhh right, just add this data-attribute to your submit button `data-dismiss="modal"`

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I don't want to close the modal, I want to find out where the form info is sent. It appears in the Laravel admin area, but I don't know how it got there.

Comment: Look your form doesn't have any action nor submit button, unless you do a javascript function that submits your form whe you click on your **Modal submit button**, your form will never be submitted to laravel

Comment: Can you please post the entire html page? I mean, in addition to posting the blade file, could you load the page in a web browser and then view the source and then post it here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your form is being submitted by JavaScript. Look through the JavaScript source files that are being included on this page. If you are using jQuery, look for something like

```
$('.inspiring').bind('click', function(e){ ... });
```

if regular JavaScript look for

```
document.forms[0].onsubmit = function () { ... } );
```

Inside there they are probably doing an ajax request, or they set the action and submit the form from there.

**Edited per comments**

The form is being submitted by this javascript file.

http://amazingyou.bravissimo.com/js/user_inspiring_backbone.js

Line 2 The URL for the form is set here.

```
InspiringStories = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/inspiring-stories',
    defaults: {

    },
    initialize: function(){
    }
});
```

Lines 17-19 Set up the click event.

```
events: {
    "click .inspiring.submit": "clicked"
},
```

Line 21 starts the clicked function

Line 78 submit the form when you hit `model.save`, everything between lines 21 & 78 is form validation.

```
this.model.save([],{
    dataType:"text",
    success:function(response) {console.log(response)},
    error:function() {}
});
```

Comment: I couldn't find anything resembling this unfortunately.
here's a link to the live page if that helps?
http://amazingyou.bravissimo.com/about

Answer (score 0):

> I can't find anything in there resembling Form::

You don't have to use the `Form::` helpers - standard HTML works fine (but misses some neat features like re-filling the fields with the submitted data if an error occurs).

> doesn't have any action or any obvious location the data gets sent to, yet it still sends data to the back-end.

A `<form>` tag with no attributes defaults to `POST`ing to the current URL. I suspect some JavaScript catches the click on the `.submit` button and causes the form tag to be submitted.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There doesn't seem to be any form handling on the page itself. Here's the live page:
http://amazingyou.bravissimo.com/about

Comment: @LiamLewis http://amazingyou.bravissimo.com/js/user_inspiring_backbone.js appears to contain the JavaScript handling the form. The block in `clicked: function(evt){` is called when the submit button is clicked.